# How do I force the Facebook Like Button to re-scrape my page?

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I created a like button on a page (http://www.usna.edu/BillAF/game.php) that sends the URL/data for it's parent page. Unfortunately, when I first put it in, an older version of the page was at the location of the parent page that did not have the open graph meta-tags on it.

So when someone "likes" the page, it sends the wrong title and a "garbage" image of half of the letter "e" on a white and gray square.

I checked: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it has the updated info. I also tried changing the associated AP ID to a new one, and neither seems to have refreshed what it sends when I "like" it. I also tried adding index.php to the end of the URL it is supposed to be posting (http://www.usna.edu/BillAF) but to no avail.

Is there anything I can do to force it to re-scrape the page? If not, does anyone know how long it will take for facebook to re-scrape it on their own?

Comment: Either it refreshes every 24 hours, or me adding a "junk" variable to the end of the url (I added ?fb=true) forced it to reset. Oddly enough while the junk variable was there, the button didn't work at all. Once I removed it, however, it re-scraped the page.

Is there a way I can close this?

Comment: You could [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) (recommended! :) or delete it by clicking the "delete" link belong the question.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to clear the facebook cached image and text is by running the tool Debugger:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

By putting the url that you are sharing there, it will refresh facebook cache from your website.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook [has an API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-update) for re-scraping page data, I use the following function:

```
function purgeFacebookCache($url, $debug=false) {

    // Set the variables for Facebook
    $fields = array(
        'id' => urlencode($url), 
        'scrape' => true
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    // Connect
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Debug
    if ($debug) {
        var_dump($result);
    }

}
```